# Are there any false positives or negatives with these IPv4 & IPv6 regular expressions?

Tags: regex, ipv6, ipv4

Trying to create a set of IPv4 and IPv6 regular expressions that are clear, concise and "covers all the bases".
Are there any problems with these?
Any alterations that can make them more useable across multiple environments/languages/scripts etc.?

```
#! /bin/bash

IP_RegEx() {

    # IPv4 Regular Expressions
    IPV4SEG='(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])'         # doted decimal notation; no leading 0 (octal) or 0x (hexadecimal)
    IPV4ADDR='(('${IPV4SEG}'\.){3,3}('${IPV4SEG}'){1,1})'
    IPV4CIDR='(3[0-2]|[12]?[0-9])'

    # IPv6 Regular Expressions
    IPV6SEG='[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}'                              # colon hextet notation; leading 0 permitted

    IPV6SEG8='('${IPV6SEG}':){7,7}('${IPV6SEG}'){1,1}'      # 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
    IPV6SEG7='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,7}(:''){1,1}'               # 1::                                 1:2:3:4:5:6:7::
    IPV6SEG6='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,6}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,1}'     # 1::8               1:2:3:4:5:6::8   1:2:3:4:5:6::8
    IPV6SEG5='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,5}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,2}'     # 1::7:8             1:2:3:4:5::7:8   1:2:3:4:5::8
    IPV6SEG4='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,4}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,3}'     # 1::6:7:8           1:2:3:4::6:7:8   1:2:3:4::8
    IPV6SEG3='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,3}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,4}'     # 1::5:6:7:8         1:2:3::5:6:7:8   1:2:3::8
    IPV6SEG2='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,2}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,5}'     # 1::4:5:6:7:8       1:2::4:5:6:7:8   1:2::8
    IPV6SEG1='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,1}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,6}'     # 1::3:4:5:6:7:8     1::3:4:5:6:7:8   1::8

    IPV6SEG0=':((:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,7}|:)'                    #  ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8    ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8  ::8       ::

    IPV6LLZI='[fF][eE]80:(:'${IPV6SEG}'){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}'  # fe80::7:8%eth0     fe80::7:8%1  (link-local IPv6 addresses with zone index)
    IPV6V4TRN='::([fF]{4,4}(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}'${IPV4ADDR}    # ::255.255.255.255  ::ffff:255.255.255.255  ::ffff:0:255.255.255.255 (IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and IPv4-translated addresses)
    IPV6V4EMB='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,4}:'${IPV4ADDR}                # 2001:db8:3:4::192.0.2.33  64:ff9b::192.0.2.33 (IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address)

    IPV6ADDR='('\
'('${IPV6SEG8}')|('${IPV6SEG7}')|('${IPV6SEG6}')|('${IPV6SEG5}')|('${IPV6SEG4}')|('${IPV6SEG3}')|('${IPV6SEG2}')|('${IPV6SEG1}')|('${IPV6SEG0}')|'\
'('${IPV6LLZI}')|('${IPV6V4TRN}')|('${IPV6V4EMB}')'\
')'

    IPV6CIDR='(12[0-8]|(1[01]|[1-9])?[0-9])'
}
```

Disclosure:  Portions acquired from various sources.

Comment: See RFC 4291: "_The "IPv4-Compatible IPv6 address" is now deprecated because the current IPv6 transition mechanisms no longer use these addresses._" You may want to consult the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ for the special ranges, and the _[IPv6 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml)_ because multicast addresses can get quite complicated with the flags and scopes.

Comment: Remember, too, that all Global IPv6 addresses are in `2000::/3`, so addresses that start with `1xxx` or `4xxx`, for example, are RESERVED today and the foreseeable future. (There is the `100::/64` discard block.)

Comment: Here's a bulletproof IPv4 matcher that I personally came up with that passes literally all tests. `^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(\.|$)){4}\b`

Comment: This strikes me as reinventing the wheel, akin to using a regular expression to verify the structure of a email address. Ruby, for example, provides a class [IPAddr](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) that provides methods for verifying and manipulating IPv4 and IPv6 address. If `str = "3ffe:5x5:2::1"`, which represents an *invalid IP*, `IPAddr.new(str)` raises the exception `#IPAddr::InvalidAddressError (invalid address: 3ffe:5x5:2::1)`, which can be caught. I would expect most high-level languages to have equivalent packages for dealing with IP addresses.

Comment: @Bren  
Won't that accept d.d.d.d. (trailing dot)?  
Also is there a spec that calls for an IPv4 address to be at the end of a line.